# Does Remote Dektop Virtualization Host provide a benefit in my use case?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, hyper-v, remote-desktop

We have a public facing Remote Desktop Session Host instance for customers of ours to demo and/or setup our [CRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) software before we send a education team to install the software on site at their business.

[image]

We recently upgraded our hardware and are now splitting various products on to separate virtual machines, Also we would like to start using the RD Web Access page to allow us to do things like RemoteApp in the future (but the software is incomparable with it right now, we need to replace a 3rd party control that does not render correctly with RemoteApp).

[image]

The VM Host is running 2008 R2 Data Center and the VMs are running 2008 R2 Enterprise. Is there any benefit to installing Remote Desktop Virtualization Host on VM Host? We are not using personal virtual desktops (from what I could tell you can only have one PVD per user and I need them to be able to access any of the three desktops (Program1's, Program2's and Program3's), also to me it seems it would require extra overhead as each user has a full VM running to themselves verses just using a shared terminal session like we do currently), and we currently do not use RemoteApp.

Will I get any benefit installing RD Virtualization Host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely no. RDVH is for VDI type deployments, where Hyper-V will be hosting VDI Desktops, people remote into a RD Session Broker that forward the connection to the appropriate desktop. This doesn't sound much like what you're wanting, at all.